# Разбить элементы списка

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как сделать из длинного списка (li) списки (ul) по 10 элементов li.
К примеру, есть один список, в котором 30 элементов:

```
<div class="list">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        ...
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

На выходе нужно получить 3 списка по 10 элементов вместо одного большого:

```
<div class="list">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        ...
        <li></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li></li>
        ...
        <li></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li></li>
        ...
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Я было нашёл функцию, которая это делает:

```
$('.list').each(function() { 
    var group;
    while((group = $(this).find('li:lt(10)').remove()).length) {
        $(this).append($('<ul/>').append(group));
    }
});
```

Да, обязательно, классов list будет несколько, поэтому для каждого нужно сделать обработку, и тут проблема - попадаем в рекурсию.
 
Если написать:

```
$('body').append($('<ul/>').append(group));
```

то всё нормально, но ведь нужно "переделать" исходный список, а не вставлять его в body. Подскажите, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может, попробуешь http://neolot.com/narabotki/autocolumnlist-jquery-plugin-dlya-razdeleniya-spiskov-na-kolonki

Comment: Спасибо, то, что нужно. Правда, хотелось получить модификацию функции выше.